# How to add Oracle SQL Constraint with 2 conditions with OR operation

Tags: oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I am working with oracle sql, and I want to add a constraint on a column such that the values in this column are included in a set of values or it can be null

I used the following DDL statement but it is not working

```
ALTER TABLE CAR 
ADD CONSTRAINT COLOR_CHECK
CHECK (COLOR IS NULL OR COLOR IN ('RED' , 'BLUE' , 'YELLOW' , 'GREEN'));
```

I get the following error, while the values in the column are 'RED' , 'BLUE' , 'YELLOW' , 'GREEN', and (null)

```
"cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"
*Cause:    an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
           populated table that had nocomplying values.
```

How can I correct the DDL Statement to apply the required action?

Comment: Your table contains values in that column that are not in the list you provided. You have to fix those values before you can add the check constraint

Comment: I am sure I included all the values.
when I add null to the IN check, the statement executes correctly, but when I try to insert a row with a different value to test the constraint, it is inserted normally although the value is not included in the condition, So I tried to divide the condition into 2 conditions, one for the null and one for the values

Answer (score 2):

Sample table and several rows:

```
SQL> create table car (name varchar2(20), color varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into car (name, color)
  2    select 'BMW', 'RED' from dual union all
  3    select 'Opel', null
  4  from dual;

2 rows created.
```

Add a constraint:

```
SQL> alter table car add constraint ch_col check (color in ('RED', 'BLUE'));

Table altered.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> -- Fail, because GREEN isn't allowed
SQL> insert into car (name, color) values ('Mercedes', 'GREEN');
insert into car (name, color) values ('Mercedes', 'GREEN')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_COL) violated


SQL> -- OK, as BLUE is allowed
SQL> insert into car (name, color) values ('Mercedes', 'BLUE');

1 row created.

SQL> -- OK, as no color is allowed
SQL> insert into car (name, color) values ('Jaguar', null);

1 row created.

SQL> -- Table contents
SQL> select * From car;

NAME                 COLOR
-------------------- ----------
BMW                  RED
Opel
Mercedes             BLUE
Jaguar

SQL>
```

---

This is what - I presume - you have:

```
SQL> -- Drop constraint
SQL> alter table car drop constraint ch_col;

Table altered.

SQL> -- Insert another "red" (note lower case) car
SQL> insert into car (name, color) values ('Ford', 'red');

1 row created.

SQL> -- Reinforce the constraint
SQL> alter table car add constraint ch_col check (color in ('RED', 'BLUE'));
alter table car add constraint ch_col check (color in ('RED', 'BLUE'))
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02293: cannot validate (SCOTT.CH_COL) - check constraint violated


SQL>
```

Wooops! Something's wrong there.

I suggest you first run the following select to find rows that are *wrong* (I mean, that prevent you from creating the constraint):

```
SQL> select color, count(*) from car group by color;

COLOR        COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
                    2
RED                 1
red                 1        --> ah, "red"!
BLUE                1

SQL>
```

Then fix the data and create the constraint:

```
SQL> update car set color = upper(color);

5 rows updated.

SQL> alter table car add constraint ch_col check (color in ('RED', 'BLUE'));

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a54e23/9